# want to output a list of dictionaries as a single dictionary in django rest api using modelserializer

Tags: django, rest, pycharm

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import NewsFeed

class NewsFeedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer to map the Model instance into JSON format."""

    class Meta:
        """Meta class to map serializer's fields with the model fields."""
        model = NewsFeed
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'image', 'source_url','source_name','metadata','created_date')
```

returns 
[This is what is returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LLyY.png)
While I want [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDPaJ.png)

notice how a list of dictionaries are sent as one single dictionary under "feeds".

Comment: where is you code for the view?

Comment: I have added the basic serialisation code which returns my model objects and want to return those all objects as on single dictionary element if that’s possible by somehow overriding the modelserializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approaching is overwrite `to_representation` method of `ModelSerializer`. Here is addition method on your `NewsFeedSerializer`

```
class NewsFeedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer to map the Model instance into JSON format."""

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(NewsFeedSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        """Modify your response data here"""
        return dict(feeds=data)
```

Comment: what is "get_feeds_data" here

Comment: `get_feeds_data` means you can reorganize `feeds` from `data` or get from other source to make your response data look like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDPaJ.png)

Comment: So basically the list I get from model Serializer can be in a dictionary as value ,key being “feeds” ?

Comment: Yes, and result from `to_representation` is the Response data that you want to return to client (browser).

Comment: doing this gets me this https://imgur.com/a/T7BMB, see how "feeds" is inside my list of dictionaries

Comment: I updated `to_representation` to return `{'feeds': [..]}`.

Comment: could you explain how

Comment: After representation instance, we have data is a list of dict. Now we just set that list into other dict. just that.

Comment: Np, you can approve my answer if it's helpful

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the accepted answer didn't work for me, so I thought I'd post how I solved this problem. I want to change a list of dictionaries to a single dictionary for ForeignKey related model instances.

**Model.py**

```
class DataSet(models.Model):
    # chart = models.OneToOneField(Chart, on_delete='CASCADE')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.title)


class Entry(models.Model):
    data_set = models.ForeignKey(DataSet, on_delete='CASCADE')
    key = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    value = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {}  {}'.format(self.data_set.title, self.key, self.value)
```

**Original Serializers.py**

```
class EntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = '__all__'


class DataSetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    entry_set = EntrySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DataSet
        fields = '__all__'
```

**API output**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "entry_set": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "key": "sum_cc",
            "value": 100,
            "data_set": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "key": "sum_cm",
            "value": 80,
            "data_set": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "key": "sum_dp",
            "value": 75,
            "data_set": 1
        }
    ],
    "title": "Dataset 1"
},
```

I replaced the line `entry_set = EntrySerializer(many=True)` in `DataSetSerializer` with the following:

```
entries = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
def get_entries(self, obj):
    return {d.key: d.value for d in obj.entry_set.all()}
```

and the output is:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "entries": {
        "sum_cc": 100,
        "sum_cm": 80,
        "sum_dp": 75
    },
    "title": "Dataset 1"
},
```

Hope it helps someone else with the same issue